# Why I cannot set percentage size for my leaflet container?

Tags: css, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using leaflet with react and I cannot use percentage for height for my leaflet container ...

I did that :

```
.leaflet-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

whereas if I put `height: 600px` instead of `height: 100%;` it works

Could you help me please ?

Here is my code :

[My code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-forked-cncji?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of height with percentage is:

> Percentages:  The percentage is calculated with respect to the height
> of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the
> containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on
> content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the
> value computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is
> relative to the initial containing block.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/height

If you want to use percentage, some parent of your element should be a defined height value or all of them should be with height: 100%.

```
/* You should place every parent as 100% */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

/* or just  */
/* .wrapper {
  height: 600px;
} */
```

> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-forked-ztkh9?file=/src/styles.css